# Can I dispatch redux action in separate from react component?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to dispatch redux action in exported to react component function. Is it possible? Or what should I do instead of this?

```
import { addToCart } from "../redux/actions/productActions";

export const checker = (item, cart) => dispatch => {
  let orderItem = {
    ...item
  };
  cart.filter(product => {
    if (product.productId === item.id) {
      orderItem = {
        id: item.id,
        quantity: product.quantity + item.quantity
      };
      dispatch(addToCart(orderItem));
    } else {
      dispatch(addToCart(orderItem));
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Just a side note. I don't think `cart.filter` is what you want to use here.

Comment: to dispatch you need access to the store. You can't just fire a random function. Also Jacob is right you are not returning in filter so don't use it. Seems you just want `forEach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a React/Redux app, you should not dispatch actions outside of React components. And React components should only dispatch actions implicitly via `mapDispatchToProps` ( https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#providing-a-mapdispatchtoprops-parameter ) or `useDispatch` ( https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#usedispatch ).